# Are patent numbers needed in titles?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I recently removed the number from [Prior art for video games played according to a selected value system such as the claimed "codes of honor"](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/79/345), but the OP replaced it. Should we have the patent number in titles?

Comment: You can find a broader discussion related to this issue here: **[What should an ideal prior art request look like?](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/47/1)**

Answer (score 2):

## No

The patent number doesn't add anything to a first impression. A link can be included in the question itself and the question tagged appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

generally agree with alex. however, the distinction between application and issued patent is important when analyzing novelty (novelty of an application is a massive undertaking given the variations of claims that can come out). i feel like indicating that the question relates to an issued patent may potentially result in more views of the question given the likelihood of a more definitive answer.